# Get the developer email

Tags: codenameone

A developer started to cowork with me to the same app. For testing purposes, I want to change some details (like remote urls and other things) according to who is the developer. I suppose that the developer cn1 account (like email) is already saved somewhere in the app by default. Is it so? How can I get it in a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Display property `built_by_user` that should be available on the device specifically:

```
String email = Display.getInstance().getProperty("built_by_user", null);
```

Or for CN.* import:

```
String email = getProperty("built_by_user", null);
```